# Interfacing with Modbus Field Device - VB.Net Program to interpret when Register is Reset

Tags: vb.net, automation, serial-port, modbus, industrial

Good afternoon,

I am maintaining a legacy program that interacts with a Modbus/RTU field device via an RS-232 physical connection with VB.Net code.  The challenge is that after replacing the original field device with a newer model, there is an inherent delay between when the device's register is reset ( Write coil 33, value 1 ) and when the particular floating point register ( 40005 & 40006 ) actually resets to 0.

As an example of what I am attempting to do, I send the command to reset to the device as a single modbus message.  Immediately after that, I will attempt to read this value to verify that the register has infact been reset by my command.  If the register is reset (in this case, <= 1.0), I will use the baseline of "0" for any readings obtained after this.  If it is not reset (this is something of a failsafe), I will use whatever value left over in the register as the new baseline (relative "0") for any readings taken after.

The problem occurs that after I issue the reset command, the device will wait something longer than at least 200 ms to actually reset the register.  This delay is more than the time it takes my program to read the register in question and establish the baseline (either 0 or the new "relative 0").  The error thus becomes that my program will assume a relative baseline which then eventually resets to 0 after enough milliseconds have passed.

See code below for example:

```
 Function resetflowmeter()
    Dim GallonSum(0) As Single

    ResetFlag4 = False  'exit reset loop

    FlowMeterWStatus = flowmeter.writeCoil(1, 33, 1) 'write "1" to reset flow meter register 
    FlowMeterRStatus = flowmeter.readMultipleFloats(1, 5, GallonSum, 1) 'read current total gallons

    If FlowMeterWStatus = 0 Then    'if modbus response message is "good"
        If FlowMeterRStatus = 0 Then    'if modbus response message is "good"
            FlowMeterUpStat = True
            If GallonSum(0) <= 1.0 Then    'if flowmeter gallons actually were reset to 0
                ResetGallons = 0 'reset new period gallons to 0
            End If
            If GallonSum(0) > 1.0 Then    'if not actually reset, set to current total
                ResetGallons = GallonSum(0)
            End If
        End If

    End If
    If FlowMeterWStatus <> 0 Then 'if reset attempt fails
        If FlowMeterRStatus = 0 Then   'if good modbus response
            ResetGallons = GallonSum(0)  'set to current sum
            FlowMeterUpStat = True
        End If
        If FlowMeterRStatus <> 0 Then 'if read attempt fails
            ResetGallons = 0
            ResetFlag4 = True 'reenter reset loop
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

For a solution, I have considered inserting a delay of approximately 250-500 ms to compensate for this.  I don't like this solution because it is arbitrary and doesn't actually give me a mechanism to check the response before proceeding with the program execution.  Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me, a Thread.Sleep between the two modbus calls is exactly what you need. Have you tried that?

Comment: Would that be essentially the same as inserting a delay?  I've considered that option...the manufacturer of the device can't give me a firm required delay time that would be required for the coprocessor of the Modbus client to update the main processor of the totalizing device.